# A simple program using 6 digit number

Tags: c++

I want to make a program where you will be asked to give a six digit number. In the screen I would print the six single-digit numbers that were given, the average of those numbers, and the min and the max.

The simplest way I thought of was to make an integer table. However, giving the 6 digit number causes the table to use spaces at each digit. Is there a simple way that I can write a 6 digit number without spaces, and do the same thing?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    float numb[6], max, min;
    int i;
    float sum;
    float average;

    cout << "Give a six digit number: ";
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cin >> numb[i];
    }

    cout << "The number you gave its :\n ";
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%f ,", numb[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        sum = sum + numb[i];
    }
    average = sum / 6;    
    cout << "Average is \n" << average;

    max = numb[0];
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (max < numb[i])
            max = numb[i];
    }
    printf("Largest element: %f", max);

    min = numb[0];
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (min > numb[i])
            min = numb[i];
    }
    printf("Smallest element: %f", min);
}
```

Comment: `printf("%f ,",numb[i]);` There's an extraneous '' there.

Comment: First, why are you storing digits in a `float` variable? Second, you should read in a `std:string` or `unsigned int` to avoid the need for spaces between the digits.

Comment: Also why are you mixing `cout` and `printf()`?

Comment: Thank you man! I am mixing cout and printf cause still i havent used the syntax of C++ still but i am gonna change printfs to cout soon. I used float cause Average that it can be float too. About std:string or unsigned int. How i can find then min and max ?With a table you can control your elements

Comment: Pay attention that a digit is a symbol while a number is a quantity; digits are generally used to represent numbers when we write, as specific sounds represent them when we talk. So a "six digit number" is an integer  number we generally write with six digits (when expressed in base 10 without leading zeros) ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
 float sum;
```

`sum` is uninitialized in your program but then also used -

```
 for(i=0;i<6;i++){
        sum=sum+numb[i];
```

Initialize it and then use it .

Comment: i am using another word for it in Greek language for sum :) But i think its not the reason of issue i am wondering how i can fix

Comment: @Nick87 initialize it to `0`  .

Comment: oh my! now i understood what you mean! Critical mistake! Fixed it! thank you sir!

Comment: @ameyCU Well, if you read that question thoroughly, you'll notice the OP currently doesn't ask how to fix that code sample.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a simple way that i just cant write a 6 digits number without spaces and do the same thing?

Do something along the lines

```
std::string input;

std::cout << "Enter a six digits number: ";
std::cin >> input;

if(input.size() == 6) {
    for(char C : input) {
 // for(size_t I = 0; I < 6; ++I) // C++98 version
    // char C = input[I]; // C++98 version
       if(std::isdigit(C)) {
           int digit = C - '0'; // convert char to a number
           // do whatever you want with the digit
       }
       else {
           std::cout << "Error in input, " << C << " is not a digit" << std::endl;
           break;
       }
   }
}
else {
   std::cout << "Error: Enter exactly six digits please" << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/OnUpCO)

---

You should note some points regarding your code sample:

1. `float` shouldn't be used to represent *digits* which are just integer numbers in the range 0 - 9. Use a `unsigned int` or so (`unsigned char` would suffice, but I don't want to add confusion).
2. If you want to have a `float` value to get the average, you need to cast the integer values participating in the calculations to `float`
3. Always initialise variables at their point of definition.

Comment: Thank you! i will try it soon as i get home and i will let you know how it went! it looks the best solution to me but i have to test it!

Comment: /home/Nightyy/propgrammatismos/Glwssesprog1/main.cpp|12|error: range-based ‘for’ loops are not allowed in C++98 mode| i am getting this error on line 12

Comment: @Nick87 You need a C++11 (current standard) capable compiler to use that syntax. I'll give you a simple example how to use it with C++98.

Comment: oh i am using Linux and Codeblocks

Comment: @Nick87 That's irrelevant, the toolchain used is what matters.

Comment: Well on Codeblocks settings it says that i am using GNU GCC compiler

Comment: @Nick87 You could install a more recent version of GCC (current version is 5.x). Anyways the C++98 version I've pointed out should work well with your compiler. As other's mentioned in their answers there may be still some other flaws/bugs in your code. I've been concentrating on your main(?) question, and just ignored the rest of your present work.

Answer (score 1):

1. `sum` is not initialized when first used.
2. The compares both compare the first element (`numb[0]`) with itself.
3. In C++ you can declare variables where you need them. That makes code far more easy to read.
4. You are mixing `printf` and `cout`
5. Your line breaks are at strange places...
6. What you read isn't a six digit number, but 6 numbers

**EDIT**: Ignoring point 6 of my list (working with 6 numbers)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Give a six digit number: ";

    //Read numbers
    float numb[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cin >> numb[i];
    }

    //Print numbers
    cout << "The number you gave its : ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cout << numb[i] << ",";
    }
    cout << endl;

    //Calculate sum
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        sum = sum + numb[i];
    }
    cout << "Sum is " << sum << endl;

    //Calculate average
    float average = sum / 6;
    cout << "Average is " << average << endl;

    //Calculate max
    float max = numb[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        if (max < numb[i])
            max = numb[i];
    }
    cout << "Maximum is " <<  max << endl;

    //Calculate min
    float min = numb[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        if (min > numb[i])
            min = numb[i];
    }
    cout << "Minimum is " << max << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Definitely looks a lot more clearly now! I am just now starting coding so i need to work indeed a lot things. Concerning point six about giving one number 6 digits may i use the code above? of std:cout ?

Comment: @Nick87 My solution reads 6 float values. As you choose `float` as data type I wasn't sure whether you really want a six-digit number or your want six numbers. That's up to you.

Comment: So if i will choose integer (i am not sure if float or integer type matters) i can use still tables like numb[i] to use one number instead six seperate numbers?

Comment: @SimonKraemer Well, if you read that question thoroughly, you'll notice the OP currently doesn't ask how to fix that code sample.

Comment: @πáv... I can't find tau on my phones keyboard... I don't expect this to be the chosen answer. In retrospect I should have used pastebin and a comment to the question.